# permission denied error while opening a config file

Tags: permissions

I have installed a software (OpenMHA) on Ubuntu. I would like to run an example which is in this software (Example.cfg).
I tried this command line: find . -name 'example.cfg' -print. 
However, I faced an error : permission denied. 
I also tried this command line: mha ?read:mha/configurations/example.cfg.
The error was: not able to open the file for reading.
I would be thankful if you could help me to run this example please.

Comment: Did you follow the official doc https://github.com/HoerTech-gGmbH/openMHA/blob/master/README.md ?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach would be to check if you have privileges to read/find in the folder you are into. You could try the same command with sudo.

I hope you manage to run your example.